# Etymology of 'patch' in the verb 'dispatch'

Tags: etymology, latin

> [dispatch (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dispatch+&searchmode=none) [<--] 
>       1510s, "to send off in a hurry," from a word in Spanish (*despachar* "expedite, hasten") or Italian (dispacciare "to dispatch"). For first element, see [dis-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dis-&allowed_in_frame=0).   **The exact source of the second element has been proposed as
>
>   [1.] Vulgar Latin * *pactare* "to fasten, fix" or * *pactiare*,
>
>   [2.] or as Latin *-pedicare* "to entrap"** (from Latin pedica "shackle;" see [impeach](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=impeach&allowed_in_frame=0)); and the Spanish and Italian words seem to be related to (perhaps opposites of) Old Provençal *empachar* "impede." See OED for full discussion.  Meaning "to get rid of by killing" is attested from 1520s. [...] As a noun, from 1540s, originally "dismissal;" sense of "a message sent speedily" is first attested 1580s.
>
> [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/54945#eid6415440) [...] Not related to French *dépêcher* , which gave the English *depesshe*, [depeach n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50229#eid7144197), common in 15–16th cent., rare after 1600, and apparently *superseded* by dispatch before 1650. [...]

1. Why was **"to fasten, fix"** proposed as a possible etymon? How does it relate?
2. Also, why was **"to entrap"** proposed as a possible etymon? How does it relate?

Please expose and explain all hidden, missing semantic drifts and links. What is a right way of interpreting the etymology, to understand how the proposed semantic jumps, abstracted and severed from the original literal meaning?

PS: I heeded Etymonline's advice to 'see OED', but neither bridges the proposed semantic jumps.

Comment: I don't know, but one could imagine that when something is dispatched it is moved- as in sent somewhere, which is the opposite of fastening it in place. To dispatch something I must first ***un**fasten* it, or free it from whatever is ***trapping*** it in place.  Incidentally *to get rid of by killing* likely refers to unfastening the soul/spirit from the body/mortal world and sending it to heaven/hell.

Comment: @Jim, you could probably submit your comment as a full fledged answer.  I can see the same semantic path explained in the  [French etymology of *dépêcher*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/depecher).  The meaning of 'to rapidly send in the afterworld' is well attested in French as well.  As an aside, the semantic evolution went even one step further in French since its main meaning is now that of 'to hurry'.

Comment: Good question; too broad. Please edit to focus closely.

Comment: To let loose, to set loose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Dispatch* seems to have been intended more in the sense of "expedite" than "send (*occasionally,* off this world)" as is more common today. Cf. *Sir Christopher said the overall impression in this case was of a child protection investigation conducted ‘with **dispatch** or perhaps undue haste’.* (ODO, see below)

[dispatch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispatch) on ODO

> Origin
>   Early 16th century: from Italian *dispacciare* or Spanish *despachar* 'expedite', from *dis-*, *des-* (expressing reversal) + the base of Italian *impacciare*, Spanish *empachar* 'hinder'.

Commentary:
Nearly everything needed appears to be already there in the question. Just a clearer semantic review is all it takes.